# Transferring (Cut and Paste) Rows from One sheet to another based on a cell value dependent on another cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a Google Sheet which has two sheets 'Enquiry' and 'Follow up'. I want a script that automatically transfers rows whose Zth column contains the word 'Complete' from the sheet 'Enquiry' to the 'Follow up' sheet. By transfer I mean rows should be deleted from 'Enquiry' and pasted in Follow up'. Also the Zth column in 'Enquiry' is dependent on the value of the column U of 'Enquiry'. I've put a condition in Z that if U = condition, then Z="Complete".

I want this to be done automatically and I don't have to run the function again and again.

So basically how it would work is,

Column U is updated in 'Enquiry'. If condition matches, column Z in 'Enquiry would become "Complete". Then this row should be deleted from here and pasted in the sheet 'Follow up'.

I've been using this code:

```
function onEdit() {
var sheetNameToWatch = "ENQUIRY";
var columnNumberToWatch = 26; 
var valueToWatch = "Complete";
var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Follow up";

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveCell();


if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
}
}
```

But this only works when I type in Complete in the column Z of Enquiry sheet and enter. Not how I'd like it to work. Please help

Comment: Hi Shiraz, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If you are having a problem with some code you have tried to write we can usually help out. I don't expect anyone here would be willing to write code for you. SO isn't a place to have developers write code for you. Have a crack at writing it yourself and then post issues that you have run into.

Comment: Have updated the post

Comment: Thanks for updating. Just want to clear this up. Your code is working fine right? You just want to change it so that you don't have to manually enter a value for it to take effect right? If so, you can always put it on a time based trigger. Check here for installing time based triggers. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable - Head to "Managing triggers manually" - This will help you setup a time based trigger. If I got it wrong, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: Yes. It's working fine. Only not working automatically. Let me try the time based trigger. Will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Time trigger isn't working.

Comment: Why is it not working? Error? Unexpected result?